# How to get Phalcon to not reload the relation each time I want to access it

Tags: phalcon

I am using Phalcon and have a model `Order` that has a one-to-many relationship with model `OrderAddress`. I access those addresses through the following function:

```
  public function getAddresses($params = null) {
    return $this->getRelated("addresses", array(
      "conditions" => "[OrderAddress].active = 'Y'"
    ));
  }
```

The `OrderAddress` model has a public property `errors` that I do not want persisted to the database. The problem I am having is that everytime I access the `getAddresses` function, it reloads the object from MySQL which completely wipes the values that I set against that property.

I really only want the `OrderAddress` models to be loaded once, so that each call to `getAddresses` doesn't make another trip to the DB- it just iterates over the collection that was already loaded.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose there's no such option in phalcon, so it has to be implemented in your code.
You could create an additional object property for cached addresses, and return it if it's already been initialized:

```
protected $cachedAddresses = null;

public function getAddresses($params = null) {
    if ($this->cachedAddresses === null) {
        $this->cachedAddresses = $this->getRelated("addresses", array(
            "conditions" => "[OrderAddress].active = 'Y'"
        ));
    }

    return $this->cachedAddresses;
}
```

This could be a quick solution, but it will be painful to repeat it if you have other relations in your code. So to keep it DRY, you could redefine a 'getRelated' method in base model so it would try to return cached relations, if they already were initialized.
It may look like this:

```
protected $cachedRelations = [];

public function getRelated($name, $params = [], $useCache = true) {
    //generate unique cache object id for current arguments,
    //so different 'getRelated' calls will return different results, as expected
    $cacheId = md5(serialize([$name, $params]));
    if (isset($this->cachedRelations[$cacheId]) && $useCache) 
        return $this->cachedRelations[$cacheId];
    else { 
        $this->cachedRelations[$cacheId] = parent::getRelated($name, $params);
        return $this->cachedRelations[$cacheId];
    }
}
```

Then, you can leave 'getAddresses' method as is, and it will perform only one database query. In case you need to update cached value, pass `false` as a third parameter.

And, this is completely untested, but even if there're any minor errors, the general logic should be clear.